# How to implement an Conditions in an Panda Data Frame, to save it

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to create a counter for a Panda DataFrame to save only until a certain Value in a  specific column.
f.e  save only until df['cycle'] == 2.

For what I gathered from the answers below is that df[df['cycle']<=2] will solve my Problem.

Edit: If I am correct python pandas always read the whole file, only if us nrows than you say f.e go to index x but want if I don't want to use Index but a specific value from a column.  How can I do that?

See my code below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

l = list(np.linspace(0,10,12))
data = [
        ('time',l),
         ('A',[0,5,0.6,-4.8,-0.3,4.9,0.2,-4.7,0.5,5,0.1,-4.6]),
         ('B',[ 0,300,20,-280,-25,290,30,-270,40,300,-10,-260]),
         ]
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict(data))
df['cycle'] = [df.index.get_loc(i) // 4 + 1 for i in  df.index]
df[df['cycle']<=2]
df.to_csv(path_or_buf='test.out', index=True, sep='\t', columns=['time','A','B','cycle'], decimal='.')
```

So I modified the answer according to the suggestion from the users.

I am glad for every help that I can get.

Comment: What is expected output ? Do you need filter by `df[df['cycle'] == 2]` ?

Comment: @jezrael I think he want `df[df['cycle'] <= 2]`

Comment: @Akhilesh - Not sure, but if it is some kind combination with reseting counter, not idea, so commnet

Comment: I tried the answer from Akhilesh and it solved my Problem.

Comment: You probably want `df[df['cycle']<=2].to_csv(path_or_buf='test.out', index=True, sep='\t', columns=['time','A','B','cycle'], decimal='.')`. Only posting as a comment because I could not understand what you mean at *Can I do it without reading the whole data frame, to save me some time and memory?*

Comment: I edited my post, maybe now my questions make more sense, I hope.

Comment: I still cannot understand. In shown code you *build* the dataframe by hand and add the `cycle` column after building it and then try to save. My previous comment explain how to **save** until a specific value. But the question seems to be how to **load**, which is unrelated to the code.

Comment: I see this was just an additional question that I had in mind. Maybe I should rephrase it or post a new one. So you are right the original question got solved.

Comment: If you are loading the file from a csv, you can use `nrows` as in `read_csv('mydata.csv', nrows = cycle * 4)` . I assume each cycle is 4 rows, and if you want to load 2 cycles, you would need to load 8 rows. Also `df['cycle'] = (df.index.values // 4 + 1).tolist()` is slightly shorter.